# Twilio Event When Switching To New TwiML

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I have started a call using the PHP Twilio API and I have sent the call to a specific TwiML URL that contains a `<Redirect>` at the end of XML. Is there anyway to know when the call is being redirected to the new TwiML URL? Possibly through webhooks or triggering an event in the new TwilML file?

Comment: That redirect is a new webhook that will be made to the new TwiML URL. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to send a notification to my web server that the TwiML URL has changed. Essentially I need to know when <say> has completed and the redirected to a new TwiML file.

Comment: Can't you use the redirect itself as the webhook that says you've been redirected?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by hosting the TwiML on my server and we I redirect to a new TwiML URL I could create it on my server and also fire an event. Thank you for the help!